# How do I stop android SearchView x button from hiding hint and bottom border?

Tags: android, searchview

By default if the SearchView x button (on the right of SearchView) is pressed while the SearchView is empty, the keyboard will hide while shrinking the SearchView to just the magnifying glass icon. This causes the bottom border of the SearchView to hide as well as the hint (placeholder). How can I remove this functionality so the SearchView never shrinks and loses its features when the x button is pressed?

Comment: hey! how did you fix this issue? the answer given by @rolandvitezhu seems to work. Could you share your knowledge? :P.

Answer (score 2):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, set an `OnCloseListener` to the `SearchView` and return `true` in it's `onClose()` method. This will prevent it's default behavior, so it will do nothing. Check the example below:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_options_menu, menu);
  MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.itemSearch);
  searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
  searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onClose() {
    return true;
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/AppTheme.WidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.WidgetTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**OR**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

or

If you want to do it programmatically , try the following

**Step2:**

```
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

**or**

```
((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't see how changing the background colour to white will magically cause the border to remain as well as the hint.